# Two-Point (or more) advantage to give the result for Review

Tags: feature-request, review-audits

[image]

As current Review's Result will judge by whoever's Q/A have 3 Point will get result (ex. Looks ok, Should be improved, Unsalvageable).

however, some Q/A is really between unsalvageable and normal question, but the point is 3 unsalvageable / 2 looks ok , then that Q/A will be go to unsalvageable.

So, I just thought that it would be good and helpful if the result will give when have 2 or more point advantage. (just like some Sports, badminton, tennis, etc.)

example. if the point is 3 / 2 (looks ok / should be improve), it's will still need more reviewer to judge it. and it will conclude if point is something like 4/2. if the point is 3/3 then it will need more reviewer to judge it.

Comment: I'm little disappoint that I got down vote without any comment..

Comment: We can't get enough stuff reviewed well as it is and you propose to make it take more time and effort for reviewers to review things.

Comment: Then it come down to - 
Adv: it help to make things more correct, Disadv: it take more time and effort

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, that is not how the SE network works generally. When you look at close votes, deleted votes, etc. there is just a fixed count. If someone disagrees, he/she should take action afterwards.

I think this will make the review process too complicated, and in the end, it will cost too much work for a single item to get completed (it can take a dozen votes or more until there is a consensus).

Comment: If it take a dozen vote, I also think that item should have some valuable thing to earn that votes